# Related to OAuth

Tags: oauth

I want to provide OAuth protocol to my own application using webservices for credentials.
How to get the secret key and consumer key to my application.

Comment: You need to be much more specific about what exactly you are trying to build.

Answer (score 0):

If it's your application, then you need to be able to generate the tokens on your server.